# Upload File is expecting file even after disabled

Tags: sitecore-forms, mvc-forms

I have a mandatory file upload field in Sitecore forms that should be disabled based on a condition of a dropdown field. Even after making the mandatory upload field optional, Sitecore is still expecting a file to be uploaded.

Is there any way to overcome this issues? Kindly find the screenshot for reference.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried not only disabling the field, but also creating a section around the field hiding the section if it's disabled like explained here https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/35770/toggling-with-mandatory-field-in-sitecore-forms ?

Comment: Yes have tried it But not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue in sitecore forms.
Please follow the below workaround.

As you can see the fxb.30da5a39-2ca9-487a-89c5-5b9f4328569f.Fields[2a03d066-f884-4106-8bf3-b5c18e79e287] field is my Single Line Text field. Now if I wanted to post the form without the required field data, then I’d just change the posted form data to my liking:
[image]

https://www.maartenwillebrands.nl/2021/07/28/sitecore-forms-bypassing-validation-and-overposting-viewmodels/

Comment: This is a link-only answer. Please provide detail so that the answer can be understood without leaving the SSE site.